# Showing an image after loading it from sql database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a problem showing the image form database in a view Details and a ImageController. Inside the view I have:

```
img src=Url.Action("GetFile","Image", new {id= Model.id})
```

and in controller:

```
public FileContentResult GetFile(int idl)
{
    //int idl = 32;
    SqlDataReader rdr; byte[] fileContent = null;
    ...........
    return File(,,);
}
```

When the view is called, function GetFile it just won't work.  But if I cut out the parameter int id1 and I instantiate it as a variable it does work.

```
public FileContentResult GetFile()
{
    int idl = 32;
    SqlDataReader rdr; byte[] fileContent = null;
    ...........
    return File(,,);
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

I think your `id` value isn't getting bound because your action parameter is `idl` and the databinder doesn't have a route value to bind to the `idl` parameter.

You see, your action parameters should match route values. I'm guessing that you are simply using the default route of `{controller}/{action}/{id}` - if this is the case then you need to change your `GetFile` action to have a parameter of `id` and not `idl`. Otherwise you need to create your own route that looks something like `Image/GetFile/{idl}.

Savvy?

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: Can't believe I missed that :D
I believe this has to be the right answer :)